# Android, How to extract system apps and perform some checks

Tags: android

I have list of appName in an array, I require a list of system apps + installed app and then need to compare it with each app in appName, if any app from list of system apps + installed is match with app from appName, then we need to check their version if different then make some action.

I have started by writing below codes:

```
private List<ApplicationInfo> getInstallapp(){

    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps;
    try {
        installedApps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        pm.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0);
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        installedApps = null;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<installedApps.size();i++){
        Log.d("Apps", "Apps are: "+installedApps.get(i).toString());
    }
    Log.d("System apps", "System apps are: " +installedApps);
    return installedApps;
}
```

but now I am stuck because I am getting each apps in below format

```
ApplicationInfo{53a4a03 com.android.providers.contacts}
```

How can I get version no. of each app and also each app of string format, so that I can compare it with my app in a list.

Please help me to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which one you want (version code or version name), but for either case, tweak your for loop to get each

```
        for(int i=0; i<installedApps.size();i++){
        PackageInfo pkgInfo=pm.getPackageInfo(installedApps.get(i).packageName,0);

                //For versionCode

     int versionCode=pkgInfo.versionCode;

          //For versionName

        String versionName=pkgInfo.versionName;

        //App name
        String appName=pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(installedApps.get(i).packageName, 0));  

   Log.d("Apps", "Apps are: "+installedApps.get(i).toString()+"version code "+versionCode+" version name "+versionName+" app name "+appName);
                }
```

Comment: when you write String appName=pkgInfo.name;
do you mean String appName=pkgInfo.pakcageName; ?

Comment: @Agutadeus, when I write String appName=pkgInfo.name; it gives me "can not resolve symbol name", rest of them are working fine.

Comment: @Pradeep Sorry, I made a mistake, it is not `pkgInfo.name` but rather `installedApps.get(i).name`, I have corrected that

Comment: AguThadeus, when I did installedApps.get(i).name; I get null as a name for all the apps

Comment: @AguThandeus, I corrected the name as you edited in your answer
String appName=pm.getApplicationLabel(pkgInfo);
but now it gives "getApplicationLabel (android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo) in PackageManager cannot be applied  to (Android.content.pm.PackageInfo)"

Comment: I don't have android studio right now so I'm writing this off my head, it should be `ApplicationInfo` instance, my bad